# How to abort the Action Abort is not working for createasyncthunk in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

How can I abort any action of createAsyncThunk?[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

That `abort` method will abort the `signal` AbortSignal instance that is passed into the thunk payload creator function as `thunkApi.signal`. If you are not actively using it (i.e. by passing it into `fetch`), calling `abort` will not have any visible effect for you.

Comment: If I want to abort on a button click then How can I do that?

Comment: Since you have not shared anything your thunk is actually doing it's impossible to answer that. But Generally you should probably just not care. If this is about an API request, the request has at this point been sent to the server, all you could cancel at this point is the last part of the answer arriving.